# winfo_width() returns 1 even after using pack()

Tags: python, tkinter, resize

I have searched online and I have tried solving it on my own but I have not been able to solve it.
Even after rendering the widget the winfo functions are returning wrong height and width

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)

label1 = Label(frame, text = "hello")
label1.pack()

label2 = Label(frame, text = "hello")
label2.pack()

label3 = Label(frame, text = "hello")
label3.pack()

frame.pack()    
print(frame.winfo_width(),frame.winfo_height())

#prints "1 1"

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 19):

You need to [update_idletasks](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method):

> Calls all pending idle tasks, without processing any other events. This can be used to carry out geometry management and redraw widgets if necessary, without calling any callbacks.

```
frame.pack()
root.update_idletasks() 
print(frame.winfo_width(), frame.winfo_height())
```